SwiftUI - pick GIF from gallery, get it's duration and display it in image view using PhotosPicker
This is what I have so far:
PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, matching: .any(of: [.images, .videos]), photoLibrary: .shared()){
    Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(height: 22)
        .foregroundColor(Color("BtnDefaultBG"))

}
.onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
    Task {

        if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
            uploadData = data

            var mimeType = Swime.mimeType(data: uploadData!)!.mime
            
            print(mimeType)
            
            if(mimeType == "image/jpeg"){
                
                image = UIImage(data: uploadData!)!

                uploadData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                
                do {
                    try await uploadToServer(mime: mimeType)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }else if(mimeType == "image/gif"){
                  
                // get gif duration
                
                image = UIImage(data: uploadData!)! // animation lost
                
                // I need to be able to do something like this: uploadData = image!.gifData()
                
                do {
                    try await uploadToServer(mime: mimeType)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
         
            }else if(videoTypes.contains(mimeType)){

            }else{
                showToastFormatNotSupported = true
            }
 
        }else{
            showToastFormatNotSupported = true
        }
    }
}

I need the picket GIF to be displayed in Image(uiImage: image!) without losing it's animation.
I also need to check the GIF duration.
And I also have the problem when uploading the GIF data to server, then couple milliseconds are missing in the end. I guess it will be solved when I upload the plain GIF instead of the whole data? So something like:
uploadData = image!.gifData()

All the question I've seen for this are outdated and for UIKit or just not what I need
Thanks in advance

"I need the picket GIF to be displayed in Image(uiImage: image!) without losing it's animation.". You can't. SwiftUI's Image doesn't support animated gifs. There are many solutions online relevant for swiftUI. From using WKWebView to custom libraries (although at least some of them probably also use WKWebView). And if you want to go the heavy duty way, you could parse Gif, extract frames as well as animation infor from it and build swiftui animation from them. Or you can convert gif to mp4

Damn, ok I can live with that but what about extracting the plain GIF to upload it to server?

Or could you show me how to convert it to mp4 and display it in a video player? I need to also handle videos anyway so I would accept the answer
